# Is there a method to add suffix onto tags fetched by git?

Tags: git

I have two projects: https://github.com/miklcct/kmb-lwb-combined-headway-eta and https://github.com/miklcct/ctb-nwfb-combined-headway-eta

These two projects share a common codebase but have significant difference. They both have tags for releases, e.g. 1.6.0 . In my development machine I use the same repository to track both projects. I want to have a way to fetch tags with a suffix added in order to recognise them, e.g. if I fetch the tag 1.6.0 from a certain remote called nwfb, the tag will be called 1.6.0-nwfb locally, however if I fetch the tag 1.6.0 from another remote called kmb, which is in a different project, the tag will be called 1.6.0-kmb locally.

Is there a way to do that automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the respect to add a *prefix* to distinguish each remote :

in your .git/config, under each `remote` section, add :

```
[remote "nwbf"]
    ...
    refs/tags/*:refs/tags/nwbf/*

[remote "kmb"]
    ...
    refs/tags/*:refs/tags/kmb/*
```

With this respect, all tags from `nwbf` will be fetched as `nwbf/[tag]` in your local repo, and likewise for `kmb`